# PrintForm to fit to one page (Landscape)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a form which uses the PrintForm method that has been placed on a button.

The following is the code which ensures the form is printed landscape, however it cuts a chunk off the left side.

```
Me.PrintForm1.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
PrintForm1.Print()
```

I was wondering if there was a simple way to fit to one page?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [msdn link](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;230502)

and [here](http://www.vbdotnetforums.com/reporting-printing/17607-scaling-form-fit-page.html)

Also, i more suggest to use print preview too, cause it can adjust the margin. Here is the [link](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_print_and_preview.html) about print preview.
But between these link, i would most suggest this code..

### Print a Form That Is Larger Than the Screen

1. Start a new Standard EXE project in Visual Basic. Form1 is created by default.
2. Add two PictureBoxes to Form1.

   Avoid drawing the second PictureBox inside the first, because doing so makes the second PictureBox a member of the first. Instead, place the origin point of the second PictureBox to the left of the origin point of the first PictureBox.
3. Right-click **Picture2** and choose **Send to Back**.
4. Add two labels to Picture1, leaving Picture2 empty.
5. Add the following code to the General Declarations section of Form1:

   ```
   Private Const twipFactor = 1440
   Private Const WM_PAINT = &HF
   Private Const WM_PRINT = &H317
   Private Const PRF_CLIENT = &H4&    ' Draw the window's client area.
   Private Const PRF_CHILDREN = &H10& ' Draw all visible child windows.
   Private Const PRF_OWNED = &H20&    ' Draw all owned windows.

   Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias _
      "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, _
      ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long

   Private Sub Form_Load()
      Dim sWide As Single, sTall As Single
      Dim rv As Long

      Me.ScaleMode = vbTwips   ' default
      sWide = 8.5
      stall = 11   ' or 14, etc.
      Me.Width = twipFactor * sWide
      Me.Height = twipFactor * stall
      With Picture1
         .Top = 0
         .Left = 0
         .Width = twipFactor * sWide
         .Height = twipFactor * stall
      End With
      With Picture2
         .Top = 0
         .Left = 0
         .Width = twipFactor * sWide
         .Height = twipFactor * stall
      End With
      With Label1
         .Caption = "Top"
         .Left = Me.Width / 2
         .Top = 0
      End With
      With Label2
         .Caption = "Bottom"
         .Top = (twipFactor * stall) - .Height * 2
         .Left = Me.Width / 2
      End With
      Me.Visible = True
      DoEvents

      Picture1.SetFocus
      Picture2.AutoRedraw = True
      rv = SendMessage(Picture1.hwnd, WM_PAINT, Picture2.hDC, 0)
      rv = SendMessage(Picture1.hwnd, WM_PRINT, Picture2.hDC, _
      PRF_CHILDREN + PRF_CLIENT + PRF_OWNED)
      Picture2.Picture = Picture2.Image
      Picture2.AutoRedraw = False

      Printer.Print ""
      Printer.PaintPicture Picture2.Picture, 0, 0
      Printer.EndDoc
   End Sub
   ```
6. Run the project.
7. The **Top** and **Bottom** labels should appear in their respective positions regardless of whether the form is completely displayed.

This code can let us adjust the width and height of the Form snapshot, so later we wanted to print it, it would just settle its own to the way we had setting.

Comment: While some of these links may contain the answer to this question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This will also help your answer remain useful even if the links you included break in the future.